# return object in soap

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, soapui

I built restful Api that called endpoint and its working, but now i try to convert this restful to soap and when i tested in soapui it return this as response

> javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException

whats the wrong?!

this is my model

public class PunchData {

```
private String requestNumber;
private String sourceId;
private String requestTimestamp;

// Getter Methods 
public String getRequestNumber() {
    return requestNumber;
}

public String getSourceId() {
    return sourceId;
}

public String getRequestTimestamp() {
    return requestTimestamp;
}

// Setter Methods 
public void setRequestNumber(String requestNumber) {
    this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
}

public void setSourceId(String sourceId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
}

public void setRequestTimestamp(String requestTimestamp) {
    this.requestTimestamp = requestTimestamp;
}
```

and this function calls endpoint

```
private static final String REST_URI = "***";
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("***", "***");
private final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

public Response createJsonPunch(PunchData punchData) {
    return client
            .register(feature)
            .target(REST_URI)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(punchData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

and this is my soap

```
@WebService
public class PunchController {

GetPunch getPunch = new GetPunch();

@WebMethod
public Response insertPunch(PunchData punchData) {
    return getPunch.createJsonPunch(punchData);
}
}
```